# Soma da diagonal principal de uma matriz no Python

Tags: python

Eu estou fazendo uma matriz[3][3] no Python onde estou somando os elementos nas diagonal principal na matriz mais ela está dando um erro.

```
i = 0 # linha
j = 0 # coluna
soma = 0
matriz = int (input("Digite a matriz (%d,%d): ",[i],[j]))
for i in matriz:
    for j in matriz:
        soma = matriz[0][0] + matriz[1][1] + matriz[2][2]

for i in matriz:
    for j in matriz:
        print ("\t {}".format(matriz[i][j]))
    print ("\n")

print ("A soma da diagona principal é {}".format(soma))
```

Saida esperada

```
5       4       6
7       5       4
3       2       3
A soma da diagonal principal e 13
```

Saida produzida:

```
TypeError: raw_input() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Comment: Se está usando a função `input`, como deu erro na função `raw_input`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está passou mais argumentos que o necessário no input (raw_input é do python 2.7 ao que me lembre e eu utilizei o 3.7), tente usar um input para i e outro para j, entretanto seu código culminaria em mais erros que eu mostro abaixo e uma versão "refatorada".

SUA VERSÃO:

```
i = 0 # linha
j = 0 # coluna
soma = 0
matriz = int (input("Digite a matriz (%d,%d): ",[i],[j])) #esse input funciona no C, mas não funciona no python

for i in matriz: # daria erro pois a matriz não foi criada

    for j in matriz: # mesmo erro de cima, entretando falta dizer qual lista da matriz você deseja percorrer

        soma = matriz[0][0] + matriz[1][1] + matriz[2][2] # caso estivesse correto ele percorreria várias vezes, assim fazendo com que a essa soma acabasse errada

for i in matriz: # o mesmo falado anteriormente
    for j in matriz:
        print ("\t {}".format(matriz[i][j]))#não está errada a sintaxe entretanto ele iria printar todos uma uma fila e não da maneira correta.

    print ("\n") # o \n seria meio inútil mas se quiser pode deixar.

print ("A soma da diagona principal é {}".format(soma)) # sem erros aqui
```

DA MANEIRA SEM OS ERROS SERIA ASSIM:

```
i = int (input("Digite o número de linhas: "))# linha
j = int (input("Digite o número de colunas: ")) # coluna
soma = 0
matriz= []
#opcional, pois serve apenas para criar uma matriz
for linha in range(0,i):
    matriz.append([])
    for coluna in range(0,j):
        matriz[linha].append(int(input ("Digite o número de {}x{}: ".format(linha+1, coluna+1))))

ll = 0 #número de linhas
lc = 0 #número de colunas

for linha in matriz:
    for coluna in matriz[ll]: #pega a matriz linha e cara um de seus objetos
        if ll == lc: #caso o número de linhas seja igual ao de colunas ele soma
            soma += coluna
        print ("\t {}".format(coluna), end = "")#se não o print cria uma nova linha
        lc +=1
    print() #serve de espaço entre linhas
    ll+=1
    lc=0 #para poder resetar o número de colunas para o próximo teste
print ("A soma da diagona principal é {}".format(soma))
```

Acredito que agora esteja tudo claro!

Comment: Acredito que seja apenas esse o erro.

Comment: Ainda não compreendi

Comment: O input é uma função e você está passando mais argumentos do que ele necessita, tente usar um input para o i e outro para o j.

Comment: Tipo assim i = int(input("Digite o número de linhas: ")) e j = int(input("Digite o número de colunas: "))

Comment: Tem mais um pequeno erro que vi agora, a sua soma vai somar múltiplas vezes.

Comment: Tentei fazer com base no que eu tinha em código C desse tipo de algoritmo, acho que é um pouco diferente no Python.

Comment: pronto agora acho que está completo pois tinha alguns erros no seu original, eu só fiz corrigir.

Comment: i = 0 # linha
j = 0 # coluna
soma = 0
matriz = int (input("Digite a matriz (%d,%d): ",[i],[j]))#dá erro
for i in matriz: # a matriz não foi criada/da erro
    for j in matriz: # pegaria apenas as linhas caso fosse criada
        soma = matriz[0][0] + matriz[1][1] + matriz[2][2]#desnecessário e somaria múltiplas vezes

for i in matriz: #mesma coisa de antes
    for j in matriz:
        print ("\t {}".format(matriz[i][j]))
    print ("\n") #você estaria dando mais de uma quebra de linha pois o print já faz isso sozinho

print ("A soma da diagona principal é {}".format(soma))

Comment: Ficou mais claro para mim, obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Que tal usar a `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

def SomaDiagonal( m, invertida=False ):
    x = np.asarray( m )
    if( invertida ):
        x = np.fliplr(x)
    return np.trace(x)

matriz = [ [1,2,2], [4,1,6], [2,8,1] ]


print ("A soma da diagonal principal eh {}".format( SomaDiagonal( matriz, False ) ))
print ("A soma da diagonal invertida eh {}".format( SomaDiagonal( matriz, True ) ))
```

Comment: Cara na matéria de Estrutura de Dados que eu tenho em Python não importamos bibliotecas, pelo menos ainda.

Answer (score 1):

Para se resolver esta questão devemos:

1. Capturar os elementos da matriz;
2. Montar a referida matriz;
3. Calcular a soma da diagonal principal;
4. Exibir a matriz criada;
5. Exibir a soma dos elementos da diagonal principal.

Pois bem, para se resolver esta questão podemos utilizar o seguinte algoritmo:

```
m = int(input('Digite o número de linhas? '))
n = int(input('Digite o número de colunas? '))

soma = 0
matrizA = list()
for c in range(1, m + 1):
    linha = list()
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        while True:
            try:
                valor = int(input(f'Digite o {i}º elemento da {c}ª linha: '))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas valores inteiros!\033[m')
        if c == i:
            soma += valor
        linha.append(valor)
    matrizA.append(linha)

print('\033[32mA matriz gerada é:')
for j in matrizA:
    for k in j:
        print(k, end='  ')
    print()

print(f'A Soma da diagonal principal é: {soma}\033[m')
```

Observe que, antes de tudo o algoritmo captura o número de `linhas` e de `colunas`. Com esses dados em mãos, o algoritmo executa o `primeiro` aninhamento de blocos `for`. É por meio deste primeiro aninhamento que a matriz será montada e, também, a soma será calculada.

Após a digitação do `valor` de cada elemento, o bloco `while` faz o tratamento do tipo de variável. Depois da aprovação, o bloco `if` verifica se nesta interação a ordem de `c` é igual a ordem de `i`. Caso positivo, a variável soma é incrementada com `valor`e a variável `valor` é adicionada na lista `linha`.

Depois que a lista `linha` esteja completa, ela será adicionada na lista `matrizA`.

Uma vez a lista `matrizA` estando completa, o algoritmo é deslocado para o segundo aninhamento de blocos `for`. Este, por sua vez, percorrerá a lista `matrizA` exibindo cada um dos elementos em forma tabular.

Posteriormente é exibida a soma dos elementos da diagonal principal.

Agora, se você deseja utilizar a biblioteca `numpy`, você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo:

```
import numpy as np

m = int(input('Digite o número de linhas? '))
n = int(input('Digite o número de colunas? '))

matrizA = list()
for c in range(1, m + 1):
    linha = list()
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        while True:
            try:
                valor = int(input(f'Digite o {i}º elemento da {c}ª linha: '))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas valores inteiros!\033[m')
        linha.append(valor)
    matrizA.append(linha)

matriz = np.array(matrizA)
soma = np.trace(matriz)
print(f'\033[32mA matriz gerada é:\n{matriz}')
print(f'A Soma da diagonal principal é: {soma}\033[m')
```

Neste segundo algoritmo a soma dos elementos da diagonal principal é calculado por intermédio do método `trace` da biblioteca `numpy`.